# Cursor Follower GSAP Animated Circle Coming Over the Text

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I am trying to achieve a cursor follower effect using gsap, but I am facing issue when I hover over the text in hero section.

[my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2zE1.png)

I want to increase the circle size when hovered over the hero text and the the text should appear over the circle. I have achieved this effect for menu icon, but not for the text.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <!-- header content -->
    </header>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <main>
        <section class='hero' data-scroll-section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="hero-line">
                    <div class='line'>
                        <h1><span>This</span> is text</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class='line'>
                        <h1>Second line</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='hero-text'>
                    <p>This is paragraph</p>
                </div>
                <div class='hero-btn'>
                    <button>Button</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

```
header {
    padding: 1rem 0;
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
}
.circle {
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 97;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 2vw;
    height: 2vw;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.hero-line {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```
var circle = document.querySelector('.circle');
var heroLine = document.querySelector('.hero-line');

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(dets){
    gsap.to(circle, {
        x: dets.clientX,
        y: dets.clientY,
        duration: .3
    })
})

heroLine.addEventListener("mousemove", function(dets) {
    gsap.to(circle, {
        scale: 3,
    })
})

heroLine.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(dets) {
    gsap.to(circle, {
        scale: 1,
    })
})
```